# echo something after json serialize in cakePHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp, jsonp, cakephp-2.0

How can I echo something at the end of the cakePHP json/xml response?

I need this in order to add JSONP support (Because i need to add the callback at the beginning and the ');' at the end

The controller uses this :

```
public function json() {

     //...code to populate $jsonObjects

     $this->set('objetos',$jsonObjects);
     $this->set('_serialize', 'objetos');
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us why you need ');' at the end of your json object? Is it something the API request is expecting?

Comment: yes, because I need it with the right syntax for jsonp (like: "mycallback(JSON_OBJECTS);" )

Comment: Doing it in the view like @inki said is the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I'm assuming you have Routes set up to correctly handle JSON/XML responses

In your routes file:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Secondly, you would need to make sure the call to your example uses the `.json` extension or the Accept header is `application/json`

You then check for the callback in your controller

```
public function json() {

    //...code to populate $jsonObjects

    // check for callback and set it
    // note: you should do Sanitize::clean() or something like that to
    // prevent code injection
    if ($this->request->params['callback']) {
        $this->set('callback', $this->request->params['callback']);
    }

    $this->set('objetos',$jsonObjects);
    $this->set('_serialize', 'objetos');
}
```

in your view file (ex: View/Users/json/index.ctp) you should have something like this:

```
if (isset($callback)) {
    echo $callback . '('.json_encode($objetos).')';
} else {
    echo json_encode($objetos);
}
```

I use something similar but didn't test the exact example above so you may need to clean it up. Also make sure you clean up the callback var so you aren't leaving a security hole by outputting exactly what is in the query string parameter.

Comment: as in [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) the `$this->set('_serialize', 'objetos');` outputs the json without the need for view files, So I guess I can do what you suggest without the serialize. Can you explain me a little more about the clean var?

Comment: If you pass a callback as a parameter in a URL, you would never want to output that directly as-is in HTML or JS. you can read more about data sanitization here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html and more about the security issues here http://tav.espians.com/sanitising-jsonp-callback-identifiers-for-security.html

Comment: I would suggest using `Sanitize::paranoid($callback)`